# How to set an icon and add an action in a facebook post using facebook api?

Tags: android, facebook, post, request

I'm using facebook-android-sdk to post a message on facebook using the bundle shown below.

The message is displayed correctly, but the icon is not shown, and I can't find a way to get something like the image below.

[image]

Is this the correct way to set an icon?

How ca I add in the bundle something like "Get Spotify" as seen in the image?

Thanks.

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("message", "icon please");
params.putString("link", "http://www.digital-farm.org");
params.putString("name", "whip'em");
params.putString("description", "description");
params.putString("picture", "http://lib.store.yahoo.net/lib/yhst-17155638221985/img-twitter.gif"); //used for testing
params.putString("icon", "http://photos-c.ak.fbcdn.net/photos-ak-snc1/v27562/74/174829003346/app_2_174829003346_2760.gif"); //used for testing

mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(mFacebook);
mAsyncRunner.request("me/feed", params, "POST", new PostRequestListener(), null);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually that icon you show in your screen shot is probably the Facebook application's icon.  It's set within the Facebook application's configuration/settings.  When you post via your Facebook application, the icon should appear automagically.  See screen shot below for example.

Assuming you're using the Facebook SDK for Android, when you instantiate your Facebook object, you pass your Facebook application's ID as parameter into the constructor.  That's how the wall posting is associated with your Facebook application.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Any idea about the "Get <appname>"?

Comment: Google around for action_links via stream.publish.  I've done this before with FBJS, but not within Java/Android.  You can find an example of the FBJS usage in the source code of this page (in iframe):  http://apps.facebook.com/compact_coverup/Results/1/10515997/Konstantin - just search for "action_links"