# How to set an icon in a facebook post using facebook api?

Tags: android, facebook

[image]

I post a message on facebook using the bundle shown below.

```
Bundle postParams = new Bundle();
postParams.putString("name", "Facebook SDK for Android");
postParams.putString("caption", "Build great social apps and get more installs.");
postParams.putString("description", "The Facebook SDK for Android makes it easier and faster to develop Facebook integrated Android apps.");
postParams.putString("link", "https://developers.facebook.com/android");
postParams.putString("picture", "https://raw.github.com/fbsamples/ios-3.x-howtos/master/Images/iossdk_logo.png");
Request request = new Request(Session.getActiveSession(), "me/feed", postParams, 
                                  HttpMethod.POST, null);
RequestAsyncTask task = new RequestAsyncTask(request);
task.execute();
```

[How to set an icon and add an action in a facebook post using facebook api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5300128/how-to-set-an-icon-and-add-an-action-in-a-facebook-post-using-facebook-api)
I had tried it, the solution can't help me.

Comment: Isn't working like that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5300128/how-to-set-an-icon-and-add-an-action-in-a-facebook-post-using-facebook-api

Answer (score 2):

You can't set it per message you post. The icon that appears there is what ever the icon you set from the developer dashboard.

Comment: But I already set the icon from the developer dashboard. When I post message to the wall in using facebook api, the icon doesn't appear.  I should do what something?

Comment: You sure under 'App Details' -> 'Primary Icons' you've set a 16x16 icon?

Comment: yes! this app is my test app, it doesn't upload to google play yet. it may be the problem?

Comment: Well, there could be many reasons. All leading to some mistake you've done. I can't tell you where exactly without checking your project.